# Different WordPress theme in subdomain for selling tickets on-line

Tags: wordpress, subdomain

I would like to create a website for a cinema. The theme that i am going to use, is not compatible with WooCommerce, so i thought i could create a subdomain, where i can install another theme for selling on-line tickets.

Comment: Your question is not about programming, which is the topic here, hence it might get closed without answers. You should probably more look at [webmasters.se] which seems more suited but you should first make sure to read its Help section and specifically the page explaining what is on topic or not and how to phrase a good question, and also of course make sure to first search on the site for similar questions as your problem may have been already discussed in the past. You will also need to close your question here after having recreated somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your hosting setup. Most hosting providers allow you to easily create a subdomain for free when you already own the domain which in turn creates a new webroot directory for you to install your WordPress/WooCommerce setup.